# Flutter: FlatButton not changing child on onPressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wanted to change a value in firestore by a button `onPressed`. I know there might be seconds delay and I wanted to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` widget while waiting. But It's not not working.

Here is my widget:

```
Widget save(String id) {
    return new FutureBuilder(
      future: PostController().isAlreadySaved(id),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.data) {
            return FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isSaveLoading = true;
                });

                PostController().deleteSaved(id);

                setState(() {
                  isSaveLoading = false;
                });
              },
              child: !isSaveLoading
                  ? Icon(
                      MyFlutterApp.star,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                    )
                  : SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                      width: 15,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
            );
          } else {
            return FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isSaveLoading = true;
                });

                PostController().save(context, id);

                setState(() {
                  isSaveLoading = false;
                });
              },
              child: !isSaveLoading
                  ? Icon(
                      MyFlutterApp.star,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  : SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                      width: 15,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
            );
          }
        } else {
          return Container(
            //color: Colors.white,
            width: Adapt.screenW(),

            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: Shimmer.fromColors(
                    baseColor: Colors.grey[400],
                    highlightColor: Colors.grey[50],
                    enabled: true,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: new Icon(
                            MyFlutterApp.star,
                            size: 30,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Here is my `isAlreadySaved()` function:

```
Future<bool> isAlreadySaved(String id) async {
    bool isSaved = false;

    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await databaseReference.collection('saved').getDocuments();

    snapshot.documents.forEach((a) async {
      if (a.data['postID'] == id&&
          a.data['saver'] == globals.currentUser.uid) {
        isSaved = true;
      }
    });
    return isSaved;
  }
```

The delete function actually deletes the document from my saved collection in firestore and the save function creates a document and saves.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because you update the widget tree too fastly, or the flutter UI thread is locked by waiting the `PostController` job to finish...

In these lines:

```dart
onPressed: () {
 setState(() {
   isSaveLoading = true;
 });

 PostController().deleteSaved(id);

 setState(() {
   isSaveLoading = false;
 });
},
```

Here I see that you want to update the **loading** state of the button. But the problem is that when you set `isSaveLoading` to `true` you don't wait for the `PostController().deleteSaved(id)` to finish before resetting `isSaveLoading` to `false`.

On another side, if `PostController().deleteSaved()` is doing a long job, since it's not async, it can lock the UI thread for a time, so you will never see your circular progress bar.

You can make the `onPressed` callback async and await for the `PostController` job.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
 setState(() {
   isSaveLoading = true;
 });

 // The deleteSaved function have to be async too
 await PostController().deleteSaved(id);

 setState(() {
   isSaveLoading = false;
 });
},
```

Hope this will help!